# Setup C# project did not complete

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# project and I want to make a setup file for this. When I followed building step to buid the .exe file, the output text in Visual studio 10 show:

```
    ------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'Setup1' ------ 
------ Pre-build validation for project 'Setup1' completed ------
------ Build started: Project: Setup1, Configuration: Debug ------
Building file 'C:\Users\Bisu\Desktop\QuanLyVatTu\Setup1\Debug\Setup1.msi'...
WARNING: Item 'Windows Installer 4.5' is required by 'SQL Server 2008 Express', but was not included.
WARNING: One of the following items 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64), .NET Framework 3.5 SP1' is required by 'SQL Server 2008 Express', but none were included.
Packaging file 'Weapons.ico'...
Packaging file 'vattu_log.ldf'...
Packaging file 'vattu.mdf'...
Packaging file 'QuanLyVatTu.exe'...
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And when I run the .exe file (after building) it cannot load successfully.
I searched for this problem but it still did not solve. So can someone tell me, how to resolve this.

Comment: The answer is right there in the output - install Windows Installer 4.5 and .NET 4...

Comment: Sometimes errors messages are helpful. Just sayin.

Answer (score 1):

just install "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)" like the error says.

Comment: I downloaded and installed .Net framework 4 (x86 and x64) but Visual still show the error